# Python/Cython return Chained function

Tags: python, functools

I am trying to return a chained function

In the below I would like to give it a list of values that map to functions. For example from the code below

```
get_function([0,1,2])
```

returns the function

```
fun(x , [a,b,c]) = a*b/x**c = mult(div(pow(x,c),b),a)
```

What I have so far is close

```
def get_function(function_params):
    def fun(x,params):
        func = x
        for i in range(1,len(function_params)):
            if function_params[i] == 0:
                func = pow(func,params[-i])
            elif function_params[i] == 1:
                func = div(func,params[-i])
            elif function_params[i] == 2:
                func = mult(func,params[-i])
        return func
    return fun
```

Obviously I could use this giant list of if statements but I would like it to be faster so returning the function will give a decent performance boost. Note: this is a MRE

Comment: So, does `get_function()` work at the moment? Why do you test (eg): `if function_params == 0:`?

Comment: @quamrana it works but it includes the if statements (benchmarked the 2 and ended up being the same). I have a list of functions to apply. Think of it like a case switch. where there will be a chain of cases to apply

Comment: It can't possibly work. You don't return func at the end. Please update your question with your real code.

Comment: edit in fun: returned func
but the outer block returning fun does return a function `<function __main__.get_trans_function.<locals>.fun(x, params)>`

Comment: And what about `if function_params == 0:`? Surely this is never `True` since `function_params = [0,1,2]`

Comment: @quamrana hahah i see my mistake I'll fix in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I don't see why you can't just make a list of the functions to be applied at the time `get_function()` is called. You have all the information about those at that time.

The only thing missing is the values of the parameters, which are given later.

```py
from operator import mul
from operator import truediv as div

def get_function(function_params):
    funcs = [lambda x,p: pow(x,p),lambda x,p: div(x,p),lambda x,p: mul(x,p)]
    funcs = [funcs[i] for i in function_params]
    def fun(x, params):
        func = x
        for f,p in zip(funcs, params):
            func = f(func, p)
        return func
    return fun

f = get_function([2,2])
print(f(5,[3,4]))
```

Output:

`60`

since `60 = (5*3)*4`

Comment: I didn't know I could create a list of functions like that! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, functions are objects too!